# How was Snape useful for the Order after the resurrection of Voldemort?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, severus-snape

Between the return of Lord Voldemort at the end of book 4, *Goblet of Fire*, and the end of the series, how was Snape useful for the Order of the Phoenix in fighting against Voldemort?